# how to show values in the second edittext only if user puts all the correct values in the first edit text

Tags: android

what should add in the code so that values are shown in the other text box only when the user have entered only corrected values...because with this code it is showing both the corrected values in the text box and incorrect in the dialog box..

```
    String s=editText1.getText().toString();
    String z[]=s.split("\\s");
    editText2.setText("");
    String a = "";
    String b = " Not valid";

    boolean is_open_dialog=false;

    for(int i=0;i<z.length;i++)
    {
        int j=Integer.parseInt(z[i]);

        if(j>=65 && j<=97)
        {
            editText2.setText(editText2.getText() + "" + String.valueOf((char) j));
        }
        else {

            is_open_dialog = true;
            a += z[i]+"\t";

        }
    }

    if(is_open_dialog){


        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(false);
        alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(a+b)
                .setPositiveButton("Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        dialog.cancel();
                    }
                });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know if I have clear your problem, but try this:

```
... 

if(is_open_dialog){

    editText2.setText("");

    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("Error");

    ...

}
```